Proof of Lemma 4.1.3 in 'Translation Surfaces' by Masur and Athreya
I am having a hard time understanding the proof of Lemma 4.1.3. They make the assertion that $q' \in \alpha^+$, but this statement seems questionable. Here is my thinking.
We note that the flow $\phi$ is explicitly stated to not be periodic. Recall that $$\alpha^+ = \{\phi_t p \ | \ t > 0 \}$$.
By the definition of $q'$ we are given that there exists some $t_0$ for which $p = \phi_{t_0} q'$. But then if for some positive $s$, we have that $\phi_{s} p = q'$ (Since $q'$ is supposed to be in the vertical flow for $p$), then we would have that $\phi_{s+t_0}p = p$, which would make this flow periodic, which is not possible.
Any clarification of my misconceptions would be appreciated. It seems to me as though they confused the statement $q' \in \alpha^+$ (false) with the statement $\phi_{t_0}q' = p$ (which is true).

As a general comment I would also humbly suggest that since the notation is not general it would be better to include all context (including all definitions of all glyphs and the statement of the lemma). This would make the discussion here helpful to possibly more people and would help getting attention faster.

You seem to be right; simply merging the last two sentences and editing as follows seems sufficient: "... or $q'$ does, in which case $p$ returns to $\beta$ at time $t_1-t_0$."
For reference purposes this lemma is on pp.64-65 of the published version; on the preprint version from April 2023 this is Lemma 4.1.2 on p.83 and there the typo is not repeated.

Here are further details; it might be useful to draw accompanying pictures.
One has $\alpha^+$ vertical starting at $p$, $\beta$ horizontal to the right of $\alpha^+$ starting at $p$. Shrinking $\beta$ to a smaller interval $\beta'$, one may assume that $\beta'$ never hits a singularity when moved vertically. Call the other endpoint of $\beta'$ $q$. Here are two important observations:
Obs.1: Any subinterval of $\beta'$ remains an interval with same angle when moved vertically.
Obs.2 (a variant of Poincaré Recurrence): Any subinterval of $\beta'$ returns to $\beta'$ infinitely often when moved vertically. (More precisely the set $\{t\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}| \phi_t(\gamma)\cap \beta'\neq\emptyset\}$ of hitting times is infinite for any $\gamma\leq \beta'$.)
For any subinterval $\gamma$ of $\beta'$ and for any nonnegative number $\tau$, denote by $t(\gamma;\tau)$ the first return time of $\gamma$ to $\beta'$ strictly larger than $\tau$. Note that if $\gamma'\leq \gamma$ then $t(\gamma';\tau)\geq t(\gamma;\tau)$.
Either $p$ returns to $\beta$ at time $t(\beta';0)$ ($=t_0$ in the notation of the authors), xor it doesn't. In the second case, we have that the image of $\beta'$ at time $t(\beta';0)$ is shifted to the left. $q$ hits $\beta'$ at time $t(\beta';0)$, hence there is a point $q'\in\beta'$ in that hits exactly $p$ at this time. Call that subinterval of $\beta'$ with endpoints $p$ and $q'$ $\beta''$.
Consider the time $t(\beta'';t(\beta';0))$ ($=t_1$ in the notation of the authors). Either $p$ hits $\beta'$ at this time, xor it doesn't. In the second case the image of $\beta'$ must have shifted to the left, hence $q'$ hits $\beta'$ at this time, thus
$$
\beta\ni\phi_{t(\beta'';t(\beta';0))}(q') = \phi_{t(\beta'';t(\beta';0))-t(\beta';0)} \circ \phi_{t(\beta';0)}(q') = \phi_{t(\beta'';t(\beta';0))-t(\beta';0)}(p).
$$
By definition the time parameter on the RHS is a well-defined positive real number.
